# Remove GDAL compiled version

Tags: gdal, debian

I've installed a compiled version of GDAL in my system (Debian Buster) to be able to use an 3.x version.
After that, i would like to remove and use the system's package (`apt-get install gdal-bin`) but, first, i should remove the compiled version. How to do it ? When i do `make uninstall` it says that nothing is intended.

Comment: Next time use `checkinstall` instead of `make install`. Now, either run `make -n install` to see where stuff got installed to (usually /usr/local/) and `sudo rm` stuff manually or try running `checkinstall` to reinstall from source. Normally `checkinstall` will overwrite everything that `make install` created. After that use `dpkg -r <package.deb>`, and everything should be removed https://askubuntu.com/a/87112

Comment: @user2856 Thanks for your answer.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall